# Get "self" of protocol with associated type

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have the following protocol:

```
protocol ViewCreator {

  associatedtype ResultView: View

  @ViewBuilder func createView() -> ResultView

}
```

and I want to get its type, for example to get its name. So I wrote the following code:

```
let typeName = String(describing: ViewCreator.self)
```

but got the following error:

> Protocol 'ViewCreator' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.

In this case how can I get "self" of the protocol with the associated type?

P.S. **I don't have an implementation** of this protocol in scope.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez get protocol type name as a string

Comment: That’s what you’re trying to _do_. What is your goal? What are you going to do once you have that string?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I want to put a factory of this protocol to the dictionary, where the key would be protocol type name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is no different than when not using an associated type.

```swift
(any ViewCreator).self
```

```swift
String(describing: (any ViewCreator).self) // "ViewCreator"
```

In the future, you may have the option to use primary associated types to provide restrictions. But for now, this will compile and execute, but be considered `<<< invalid type >>>`.

```swift
protocol ViewCreator<ResultView> {
```

```swift
(any ViewCreator<EmptyView>).self
```

Comment: When I don't use associatedtype everything works correctly. I don't understand your examples with "(any..." and generics in the protocol, they don't compile for me.

Comment: That’s because you’re not using the current version of Swift. Switch to the Xcode beta.